# why the explicit conversion function of derived class return type is not a candidate in the context of direct-initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

Given the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(A const&){}
};
struct B:A{};
struct C{
    explicit operator B(){
        return B{};
    }
};

int main(){
   C c;
   A a(c);  // #1
}
```

[`GCC` and `Clang`](https://godbolt.org/z/fPTzM5) both report that `c` cannot be converted to `const A&`.  However, there's a relevant rule in the standard says, `explicit operator B()` should be a candidate function in this context. That is:
[over.match.copy#1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.copy#1.2)

> When initializing a temporary to be bound to the first parameter of a constructor where the parameter is of type “reference to possibly cv-qualified T” and **the constructor is called with a single argument in the context of direct-initialization of an object of type “cv2 T”, explicit conversion functions are also considered**. Those that are not hidden within S and **yield a type whose cv-unqualified version is the same type as T or is a derived class thereof are candidate functions**.

Moreover, in the current standard, the relevant rule still has the same meaning:
[over.match.copy#1.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy#1.2)

> When the type of the initializer expression is a class type “cv S”, conversion functions are considered. The permissible types for non-explicit conversion functions are **T and any class derived from T**. **When initializing a temporary object ([class.mem]) to be bound to the first parameter of a constructor where the parameter is of type “reference to cv2 T” and the constructor is called with a single argument in the context of direct-initialization of an object of type “cv3 T”**, the permissible types for explicit conversion functions are **the same**; otherwise there are none.

Regardless of c++17 standard or the current standard, they all say that in the context likes `#1`, the explicit conversion function that has the return type of class `T` or any class derived from `T` is also a candidate.

In my example, The object `a` of type `A` is direct-initialized by the single initializer `c`, which is the single argument in the invocation of constructor, the copy constructor of `A` has a parameter `A const&`.  In this case, `c` should be used to initialize a temporary object to be bound to the first parameter. Hence, in this case `explicit operator B()` should be considered as a candidate function. However, `GCC` and `Clang` both reject this example.  `GCC` obviously report a dignosis information that make no sense.
Is it a bug of these compilers? Or, I misunderstand something?

Comment: I think that it is somewhat the **expected behavior**... That code does not compile with Visual C++. If I remove `explicit`or if I return an `A` from the conversion it will compile. My understanding would be that the part **cv2 T...cv3 T** imply that an **explicit** conversion operator should give a T and not an S (which would be in the category: **otherwise, they are none**). *Side note: the purpose of explicit is to avoid unwanted conversion and for me slicing is generally undesirable...*

Comment: @Phil1970  I didn't say the return type is `S`. Note this wording:"The permissible types for non-explicit conversion functions are T and any class derived from T" and "the permissible types for explicit conversion functions are the same; ". So,  not only `T` but also any type derived from `T` should also be considered.

Comment: Assuming that compilers are right and specification somewhat hard to understand, my thinking is that **the second specification mostly fix the hole** (in the first one) by adding the part that talk about **cv3 T** In your example `A` would be `T` and `B` would be `S`. As your conversion is explicit, you have **cv3 S** as the return of your conversion and you fall in the **otherwise there are none** category. I am pretty sure that the new wording is to fix the unwanted conversion in your code. If you really want that conversion, you either remove `explicit` or add conversion to `A`.

Comment: Another point of view is that you have 2 conversions: `C` to `B` and `B` to `A`. When using `explicit`, you generally want only one conversion. **Otherwise, tell me the difference between explicit or not**.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372442/explicit-conversion-functions-direct-initialization-and-converting-constructor?rq=1 and other **related** questions

Comment: @Phil1970 Through concluding [over.match.ref#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref#1) and [over.match.conv#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.conv#1), they basically say that `explicit conversion functions` are considered as candidate when occurring in **direct-initialization**. However, [over.match.copy#1.2] is a special rule, which permits explicit conversion function to be a candidate when occurring in parameter initialization(**copy-initialization**), as long as the object be initialized whose cv unqualified type is the same as the type referenced by the parameter of the constructor

Comment: @Phil1970 As I said in the question, the object `a` be initialized is of **class type A**, the initializer expression `c` has **class type C**, and the parameter of copy constructor is a reference to const A. So, "When initializing a temporary object..." apply here. Taken `A` as `T` and Taken `C` as `S`. C++17 says that those conversion functions whose return type is T or any class type derived from T are candidate functions. C++20 says "the permissible types for explicit conversion functions are the same". So, the vague is at `the same`. My reading is the same as that for conversion functions

Comment: I guess this is a bug, but I can't find any similar bug report. You can try to report the bug and see how the compiler authors reply.

Comment: I think [over.match.copy]/1 is, at the very least, confusing, as it speaks about a special case for _a_ (single) user-defined conversion via an explicit conversion function, allowed in direct initialization (which is aligned with [class.conv.fct]/2), but goes on to expand the special case to allow these explicit conversion functions also in user-defined conversion _sequences_, as we require a standard conversion (_derived-to-based Conversion_, which has Conversion rank) to convert the result of the conversion function to the target type. To add to the confusion, the sibling section ...

Comment: ... [over.match.conv] has another take on the special case, as it explicitly allows a standard conversion sequence to follow the user-defined conversion by non-explicit conversion functions, but limits this to only allow qualification conversions to follow the user-defined conversion when it is by an explicit conversion function. This could arguably explain GCC:s error note, as it points out that it cannot convert the result of the user-defined conversion to the target type by only a qualification conversion. Arguably GCC has implemented the same restriction for [....copy] as for [...conv].

Comment: @dfrib  the second standard conversion sequence of explicit conversion functions specified by [over.match.conv] is no problem. It's consistent with the result of [compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/MKhhYv).

Comment: @jackX I'm aware of that, but I'm saying that both GCC and Clang seems to have implemented the same limitations that are specified in [over.match.conv] also to [over.match.copy] - their differences are subtle and moreover both special cases where the general rules for user-defined conversion _sequences_ does not apply, as per [\[over.best.ics\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.best.ics#4). Namely that user-defined conversions that are using explicit conversion functions (in direct init) may only be followed by a qual. conversion, but not by any other standard conversions.

Comment: @xskxzr  I considered it a bug. Since a conversion function whose return type is `A` is, why wouldn't `B` which is derived `A`  be. Isn't `B` is-A?

Comment: In [this example of yours](https://godbolt.org/z/fs6r3E), only a qualification conversion is required after the user-defined conversion (by an explicit conversion function), and both Clang and GCC accepts it (whilst arguably wrongly rejecting your original example). _"GCC obviously report a diagnosis information that make no sense."_ - note that GCC:s diagnosis makes sense if we assume they have (wrongly?) imposed the same restrictions as [over.match.conv] also for [over.match.copy], regarding explicit conversion functions (and subsequent qualification only conv. vs any standard conversions).

Comment: @dfrib Well, why are other standard conversions not permitted by 2nd standard ics of conversion functions, Rather, only qual. conversion. is permitted. Maybe, I only say the standard says it. IMO, since explicit conversion functions are permitted in direct-initialization, why not the other respects keep consistent with that of non-explicit conversion functions, Right? I guess that it may have some troubles in these contexts if other standard conversion would be permitted.

Comment: @dfrib Please note the qualification for the second standard conversion which shall be a qualified conversion, this whole section is used for initializing the **non-class object**, [over.match.conv#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.conv#1). In my example, the object be initialized is of class type, so [over.match.copy#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy#1) applies to my example rather than [over.match.conv].

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding my comments above (and that we are actually agreeing): I think GCC and Clang are both wrongly interpreting and implementing [over.match.copy], which is for class-type target object. I'm thereafter speculating that *the reason* for this misinterpretation is that they are using the same restrictions as from [over.match.conv] (and  [over.match.ref]) also when implementing [over.match.copy], even if the former applies to non-class target types (and reference type target types, respectively). The differences between [over.match.conv] and  /copy] are quite subtle.

Comment: ... And indeed, if we [take a look at clang's implementation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/979c38cc74f4e96c5e1bee1f966a81038fff1ed6/clang/lib/Sema/SemaOverload.cpp#L7282-L7284), we see that they implement their candidate selector for conversion functions for [over.match.copy] using a predicate for the explicit special case [that is based on \[over.match.conv\]](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/979c38cc74f4e96c5e1bee1f966a81038fff1ed6/clang/lib/Sema/SemaOverload.cpp#L7233). I would argue that this is a bug.

Comment: @dfrib Oh, I have understood your meaning.  I have reworded my opinions in [Bug 98554](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98554) to make it more clear.

Comment: @dfrib Actually, IIUC, [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/rE4nrf) still does not obey the standard, my argument is, there's no temporary object to be created here. The reference is directly binding. So, the special case "When initializing a temporary object ..." shouldn't apply to this example.

Comment: Hmm that example is interesting: could it be allowed under [\[class.conv.fct\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#2.sentence-1) and [\[dcl.init.general\]/16.5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#15.6.2), as the user-defined conversion converts to a _reference_ of the destination type rather than to the destination type? Otherwise [\[dcl.init.general\]/16.5.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#15.6.3) applies and we are back to [over.match.copy], which only allows explicit conversion functions for when initializing temporary objects, which would disallow the example.

Comment: @dfrib  In this declaration `A a(c);` where the object `a` is **direct-initialized** by the initializer `c`, so [dcl.init.general#15.6.2] first apply here in order to choose the constructor for this initialization. While taking the `c` as the argument to invoke the constructor `A(A const&)` where the parameter is **copy-initialized** from the argument as per [dcl.init#general-13](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-13). Hence, it's neither a direct-initialization nor the parameter is bound to **temporary**. So, the special rules shouldn't apply here.